# How to query in firebase firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection and inside the collection, I have multiple documents.
I want to get the documentId of the document which has the data according to my whereEquals()
value. But every time it returns only the first document data it does not search for the data in the second document.

[image]

```
firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference collectionReference=firebaseFirestore.collection("Planes");
    Query query=collectionReference.whereEqualTo("starting",startAirport).whereEqualTo("destination",destinationAirport);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Planes> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Planes>()
            .setQuery(query, Planes.class)
            .build();
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it should return the second document?  We can't see what it contains, and we don't know the values you're searching for in the code.

Comment: i am passing the destination and starting but it found the matches of only first document..i want it to search for all the documents@DougStevenson

Comment: I see that.  What I am saying is that we can't see the values of the variables you're passing, and we can't see the values in the second document.  So, we can't tell if you're doing something wrong.  Please edit the question to make it clear why you think the second document should be found, and include the details.

Comment: i have posted the values of the second document..check that out @DougStevenson

Comment: Why do you expect the second document to match in the same was as the first?  They don't have anything in common except price, and you're not using that in the query.

Comment: i am passing the startingAirport and destinationAirport so it has to fetch the matching document..am i doing it wrong??@DougStevenson

Comment: the thing is if i am passing the field values of second Document it shows nothing to me in the recyclerView But if i pass the field Value of the first document then it shows the document in the recyclerView...like.startingAirport=pune and destinationAirport=delhi...so in this case it shows the document in the recyclerView but if i pass startingAirport=Delhi and destinationAirport=mumbai...it fetches nothing why??@DougStevenson

Comment: @DougStevenson   am i doing it wrong?